# Using Mysqli: Is there a way to not have to connect to the database every single query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I have just begun working with `MYSQLi` instead of `MYSQL`, and I have run into a huge annoyance: having to connect to the database every single query and such. Why do I have to do this now when I didn't in old MYSQL? Or is there a way not to have to do this?

A couple examples:

Mysql:

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table");
```

Now in Mysqli I always have to do:

```
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id FROM table");
```

also I have to do this with:

```
mysqli_last_id($db);
```

and

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($db);
```

I have tried to find the answer to this all night, but I can't find anything.

Comment: The MySQL extension was trying to reuse the latest connection made with `mysql_connect` in the global scope. Which was unintuitive and dangerous when handling multiple connections in the same script. This is one of the reason it was deprecated. You should really use the object oriented version of MySQLi, create a db object and reuse it through your script.

Comment: Create your own database class, OOP to the rescue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some things to clarify

1. You don't have to **connect** every time. Connecting to database is different thing, one when you're calling mysqli_connect() and you should do it only **once** per application.
2. So, you're talking of just using connection **resource** variable.
3. Yes, you have to pass it in every function. Not a big deal, nothing to talk of.
4. The only issue could be with variable scope. Use `global $db;` inside a function.
5. Moving to mysqli just mechanically, using new functions old way **makes absolutely no sense.** If you want to keep using mysqli_real_escape_string in the application code - don't bother with transition at all and keep with mysql.
6. The only reason (quite weak though) for move - to use prepared statements.
7. Mysqli's support for prepared statements is awful
8. So, better quit mysqli and go for [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)
9. Nevertheless, using raw API functions, be it mysql, mysqli or PDO, is ugly. One have to adopt some **abstraction library** to be used in the application code instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, don't use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated. Use PDO instead

http://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.construct.php

```
$pdo = new PDO(/* Connection options */);

$rows = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM table")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
   print_r($row);
}

$pdo->query("INSERT INTO table SET field1 = 'value1'");
```

Comment: I'm using `MySQLi_` not `MySQL_`

Comment: Its almost the same... use better, PDO. [but at the end, I think it is a persona decision...](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/)

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [DALMP Database Abstraction Layer for MySQL using PHP.](http://dalmp.readthedocs.org/en/latest) is uses pure mysqli and connects to database only when needed, when possible get the results from the cache, with out touching the database.

Examples of using the cache can be found here [Cache & prepared statements](http://dalmp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cache.html)